# Assemble an lParam message, is this the correct code?

Tags: c, winapi

I coded the code below. I've used it in my program and it seems to work.
Anyway, I'm asking if is it correct.

```
int SendMessageWMSIZE(HWND hwnd) {
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd,&rc);
    int lParam_my;
    short low=rc.right-rc.left; // LOWORD
    short high=rc.bottom-rc.top; // HIWORD
    lParam_my=(high<<16)|low;  // construct an int 32 from two int 16

    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SIZE, 0, lParam_my);

    return lParam_my;
}
```

Don't I have to change the "short" with "int" (I can shift an 32 int by 16, but shifting a 16 by 16)?

Why it works either if I use "short" or "int" instead of shorts?

Comment: You might want to use the supplied [macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468920(v=vs.85).aspx) for such compositions. [MAKELPARAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661(v=vs.85).aspx), for instance, will save you from worrying about the bit shifting stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be more idiomatic to use the [`MAKELPARAM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661.aspx) macro.

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SIZE, 0, MAKELPARAM(low, high));
```